# What is the fastest way to copy a large file to S3 from Node.js?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-cli

I imagine using `child_process` with the AWS CLI using `aws s3 cp` is faster than using the `aws-sdk` module, but I'm wondering if this has actually been tested before? Is there a faster way to copy files asynchronously from a Node.js environment, ideally using a separate thread?

Answer (score 0):

To copy single file to S3 bucket:

aws s3 cp filename s3://bucket/ --recursive

To copy all files in a directory to S3 bucket:

aws s3 sync directory/ s3://bucket/ --recursive

Comment: I ran a test locally, though, and using the JS SDK is actually faster than the CLI...